# Why is request_time much larger than upstream_response_time in nginx access.log?

Tags: networking, nginx, latency

I am trying to improve the performance of a web app. Profiling the app itself, I found its response time are quite acceptable (100ms-200ms), but when I use ApacheBench to test the app, the response time sometimes exceeds 1 second. When I looked closely at the logs, I found a big discrepancy between `request_time` and `upstream_response_time` occasionally:

```
"GET /wsq/p/12 HTTP/1.0" 200 114081 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" 0.940 0.286
"GET /wsq/p/31 HTTP/1.0" 200 114081 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" 0.200 0.086
```

The `upstream_response_time` is quite close to my profiling in the web app, but `request_time` is close to one second for the first request.

What could cause this discrepancy?

I understand `request_time` is recorded from the first byte received to last response byte sent, it can be affected by network condition and client problem. I am wondering what should I do to reduce the average `request_time` as much as possible?

Comment: What I am looking for is some Nginx parameter tuning to reduce the request_time?

Comment: Hi @NeoWang, I am also facing with similar problem. Were you able to pinpoint the source of the problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A high `request_time` may be, among others, due to a client with a slow connection, for which you can't do much about. Thus, a high `request_time` does *not necessarily* represent the performance of your server and/or application.

*You really should not spend too much time on `request_time`* when profiling but instead measure things like the application's response time (ie. `upstream_response_time`).

That said, there are some things which you are able to do and *may* affect the `request_time`. Some of them are the following:

- Move your server on a high-speed network
- Move your server near the client
- Disable the [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)
- Tune the server's TCP stack (see [this article](https://fasterdata.es.net/host-tuning/linux/)). However these won't necessarily make a big difference since the kernel does a good job of tuning them for you.