# How can request_time be less than upstream_response_time in nginx?

Tags: performance, nginx, networking

I understand how nginx's [request_time can be larger than upstream_response_time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37430951/518169), it simply means that the network connection was slow between nginx and the client.

What I don't understand is how `request_time` can be less?

I've analysed an nginx log where nginx is in front of an API. There were about 2.6 millions lines, thus I believe it's a good sample (only API requests were analysed, no static files.)

Ratios were calculated like:

`ratio = request_time / upstream_response_time`

The mean of the ratios is 1.04, thus on average `request_time` is a tiny bit larger than `upstream_response_time`, which sounds reasonable.

I made a histogram to visualise this. What I don't understand is the left side of the histogram, where values are < 1.0.

[image: histogram]

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out about this? I am seeing this too.

Comment: No I haven't yet.

Answer (score 10):

$upstream_response_time calculated by `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE)`, and by default it can be in past for 4 milliseconds, on opposite, $request_time calculated by `gettimeofday()`. So eventually upstream_response_time might be larger, than response_time.

Based on [nginx forum thread](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?21,284448,284450#msg-284450)